# Android studio cant recognize phone in charging mode

Tags: android, usb

Ok so I have this wired problem. I have a newly installed android studio and latest usb SDK installed. I have connected my phone through USB and android studio cant recognize my phone, but when I switch to file transfer it works perfectly. this is kinda annoying I need to choose **file transfer mode** every time I check for output. this seems strange and I have gone through several article but none of them seems have this problem.

Feel free to share your thoughts.

Comment: See if your device lets you change the default USB mode in Settings somewhere.

Comment: I been using this device before for checking outputs. and this problem happening in my new android studio. plus i don't think there is a option to change default USB mode for android devices.

Comment: "i don't think there is a option to change default USB mode for android devices" -- it varies by device. I have definitely seen it in some, though I haven't looked for it in recent years. Perhaps you need an updated driver, if you are on Windows.

Comment: i have checked my device(one plus 3) preference, it seems it don't have any of those option. I am using latest drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Exact Solution for your problem. But alternatively it will give solution for you.

In Android Setting-> Developer Option -> Select USB Configuration you can choose **File Transfer mode** as Default one. So that you no need to change at every time.

Hope it will Help you!!!

Comment: There is no option for USB configuration

Comment: @Fajar Khan Can i know your phone model and android version?

Comment: using one plus 3 android 6.0

Comment: @Fajar Khan  Please check the following Link. It will help you to change default usb configuration. [http://www.addictivetips.com/android/how-to-set-the-default-usb-connection-type-in-android-6-0/](http://www.addictivetips.com/android/how-to-set-the-default-usb-connection-type-in-android-6-0/)